Is there a way to create custom loss functions?
I would like to have the flexibility of using MedianSquaredError, LogCoshError, and other custom loss functions etc. when fitting my sklearn models.
For _GeneralizedLinearRegressor and HistGradientBoostingRegressor, there is the flexibility of extending the estimator to use different loss functions, which are already there in sklearn. I checked out Random Forest Regressor using a custom objective/ loss function (Python/ Sklearn) where a user mentioned:

So it could be done as discussed within the issues, by forking sklearn, implementing the cost function in Cython and then adding it to the list of available 'criterion'".

But there does not seem these 'CyLoss' functions such as CyAbsoluteError as referenced in sklearn code, but I can't seem to find their definition. This is the best I could find: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/_loss/_loss.pxd#L36
There is a related GitHub discussion, but it seems to have been closed without a code example when I found it: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/discussions/21614
I tried
from sklearn.linear_model._glm.glm import _GeneralizedLinearRegressor
from sklearn._loss.loss import (
    HalfGammaLoss,
    HalfPoissonLoss,
    HalfSquaredError,
    HalfTweedieLoss,
    HalfTweedieLossIdentity,
    BaseLoss,
    AbsoluteError
)
from sklearn.utils.stats import _weighted_percentile
from sklearn._loss.link import (
    HalfLogitLink,
    IdentityLink,
    Interval,
    LogitLink,
    LogLink,
    MultinomialLogit,
)
from sklearn._loss._loss import (
    CyAbsoluteError,
    CyExponentialLoss,
    CyHalfBinomialLoss,
    CyHalfGammaLoss,
    CyHalfMultinomialLoss,
    CyHalfPoissonLoss,
    CyHalfSquaredError,
    CyHalfTweedieLoss,
    CyHalfTweedieLossIdentity,
    CyHuberLoss,
    CyPinballLoss,
)

class CustomError(BaseLoss):
    differentiable = False
    need_update_leaves_values = True

    def __init__(self, sample_weight=None):
        super().__init__(closs=CyAbsoluteError(), link=IdentityLink()) # where is the CyAbsoluteError definition?
        self.approx_hessian = True
        self.constant_hessian = sample_weight is None

    def fit_intercept_only(self, y_true, sample_weight=None):
        if sample_weight is None:
            return np.mean(y_true, axis=0)
        else:
            return np.average(y_true, sample_weight, axis=0)



